# How to use stats::reshape() to convert wide data format to long?

Tags: r

I would like to replace `tidyr::pivot_longer()` with `stats::reshape()` to convert wide data format to long. How can I do this?

```
library("tidyr")
set.seed(42)
n = 10
df_wide = data.frame(A = runif(n), B = runif(n), C = runif(n),
                     group = as.factor(sample(1:3, size = n, replace = TRUE)))
head(df_wide)
#           A          B         C group
# 1 0.9148060 0.4577418 0.90403139     2
# 2 0.9370754 0.7191123 0.13871017     3
# 3 0.2861395 0.9346722 0.98889173     2

df_long = pivot_longer(df_wide, cols = 1:3, names_to = "column", values_to = "value")
head(df_long)
#   group column value
# 1 2     A      0.915
# 2 2     B      0.458
# 3 2     C      0.904
```

Update: This solution proposed by @MrFlick in the comment seems to be closest to the `tidyr` code, with the difference that `stats::reshape()` modifies the row names:

```
df_long = reshape(df_wide, direction = "long", varying = 1:3, v.names = "value",
                  timevar = "column", times = c("A", "B", "C")) |>
  subset(select = -id)
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I see this is a dupe, where https://stackoverflow.com/a/2185525/3358272 provides a good basis. I'll keep my answer as-is for now, but closing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
out <- reshape(df_wide, direction="long", varying=c("A","B","C"), v.names="value") |>
  transform(column = c("A", "B", "C")[time], id = NULL, time = NULL)
out <- out[order(out$group, out$column),]
head(out)
#     group     value column
# 4.1     1 0.8304476      A
# 4.2     1 0.2554288      B
# 4.3     1 0.9466682      C
# 1.1     2 0.9148060      A
# 3.1     2 0.2861395      A
# 5.1     2 0.6417455      A
```

Normally the `time` variable is the *index* of the column, not the column name itself; while I find it slightly annoying (especially now that I'm comfortable with `tidyr::pivot_*` and `data.table::melt/dcast`), it is easy enough to fix using the `[time]` part. The only reason I put the "named" variant into `column` and removed the `time` variable is to make the names the same as your `pivot_longer` code ... I could have easily done `time = c(...)[time]` instead.

`reshape` "needs" an `id` var, so if we don't provide one, it injects one itself (as the row numbers). There is no strict need to remove it, but again for comparison with your `pivot_longer` code, I removed it. (I actually think having `id` added by default is not a horrible thing, there have been times in `tidyr`'s past where one needed to pre-add row number so that the reshaping could occur error-free.)

For comparison:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df_wide, cols = 1:3, names_to = "column", values_to = "value") |>
  arrange(group, column) |>
  head()
# # A tibble: 6 × 3
#   group column value
#   <fct> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 1     A      0.830
# 2 1     B      0.255
# 3 1     C      0.947
# 4 2     A      0.915
# 5 2     A      0.286
# 6 2     A      0.642
```

---

Data, using `set.seed` for reproducibility:

```r
set.seed(42)
n = 10
df_wide = data.frame(A = runif(n), B = runif(n), C = runif(n),
                 group = as.factor(sample(1:3, size = n, replace = TRUE)))
```

Comment: I think this also works. `reshape(df_wide, direction="long",times=c("A","B","C"), timevar="column", varying=list(c("A","B","C"))) |> subset(select=-id)` It really does show off how much better the pivot functions have become.

Comment: Thanks, MrFlick! Honestly, I answered this question as much to remind myself how to work with `stats::reshape` ... actually, to remind myself how painful it is to work with that now that I'm more familiar/comfortable with `reshape2`, `tidyr`, and `data.table` pivoting functions.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed the `reshape()` interface is painful. I will stay with `tidyr`.

Comment: `reshape()` also changes the row names compared to `tidyr`.

Comment: Indeed ... perhaps because (or related to why) `tidyr` and many (most?) functions in the tidyverse ignore or actively remove row names. I generally don't rely on row-names, though I accept many find them useful.